# Sketching a complex set

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

The set is as follows: $$M = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 < |z+2-i| \le 2 \cap \operatorname{Im}(z+i) > 2\}$$

If I assume that $z = x + yi$, the first term reduces to $$|x + 2 + i(y-1)|$$ which should thus result in $$1 < \sqrt{(x+2)^2-(y-1)^2} \le 2$$ or $$1 < (x+2)^2-(y-1)^2 \le 4$$ To my understading this is a ring around $(-2,- 1)$ in the complex plane with inner radius of 1 (excluding $r=1$) and outer radius $4$.

Furthermore, the second term would be $\operatorname{Im}(x+i(y+1) > 2$, reducing to $y > 1$. This should include all points in the complex plane above $y=1$.

The solution would obviously include all points that fullfill both requirements.

Is my thinking here correct or did I make a mistake somewhere? 
I'm sorry if this may be considered help with homework, but we haven't explicitly talked about sketching of complex sets at all and I'm trying to make sense of the task we got.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The first set is an annulus centred at $(-2,1)$ with inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$, and the second set is all points above the line $y=1$

I hope this helps

Comment: I supposse you just read the coordinates of the center of the ring by looking at the inequality? If that's the case, do you have an idea why my algebraic result is off?

Comment: You should have not squared the $i$ when calculating the modulus, and the outer radius is clearly $2$ not $4$

Comment: You are right, that explains why I got a negative y coordinate. Also, I just realised that the formular for a circle is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so that also explains why I shouldn't square the result. I'm tired.. Anyways, thank you very much for helping me out!